# Algorithm for the maximum weight connected subgraph of a given order

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, subgraph

Does [Networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/index.html) have an algorithm for finding the maximum weight connected subgraph of a given order (i.e. no. of vertices)?

Comment: You can test for the existence of a clique of size k with that primitive, so if it exists, it may not be fast enough on the graphs you care about.

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [induced_subgraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.induced_subgraph.html?highlight=induced%20subgraph#networkx.classes.function.induced_subgraph) provide the necessary ingredients for exhaustive search.